# How to make sidebar form fixed only on large screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I have the following layout. In mobile the layout works fine it is what I want, I want the content to flow full screen followed by the sidebar form. However in desktop I need the sidebar form to stay fixed to the view port while scrolling.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
      <h1>Page Heading</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-1">
      <!-- Page content here -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="form-holder">
        <!-- form here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How do I make the form scroll to top along with content stay fixed on top only on desktop and flow freely on smaller screens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`media query`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). You can see the `width` values of the screen when you set each bootstrap `xs`, `sm`, `lg` or `xl`[here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 940px){
   .form-holder{
       position: fixed;
   }
}
```

Comment: While your answer is correct in some level, Its not what I need, there are two problems, 1) my form starts below the view port so I want it to scroll with content to top and stay there. 2) `position: fixed` breaks the form out of layout

Comment: When you have the form fixed you can use `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` properties to set it on the screen. A link to a working example would be great to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

### The @media Rule

You can dynamically change any css rule based on many factors, the one we want being **screen size**

This rule is used as follows

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    --Css rules--
}
```

Common selectors include min-width, max-width, min-height and max-height. using `(min-width: 480px)` would only apply the rule to screen sizes to screens larger than 480px.

If you want to read more, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) is a great readup on it

Answer (score 0):

Just check the bootstrap, Example: Mobile and desktop: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed

```
<!-- Stack the columns on mobile by making one full-width and the other half-width -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns are always 50% wide, on mobile and desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
</div>
```